# Настройка маршрутизации для 2 сетевых карт Windows 10

Tags: маршрутизация

[image: Схема]

ПК 1 и 2 в одной сети:

ПК 1 ip 192.168.1.10
ПК 2(первая карта) ip 192.168.1.10

ПК 3 подключен второй сетевой картой к другой сети:

ПК 3 ip 10.0.0.33
ПК 2(вторая карта) ip 10.0.0.34

Неободимо с ПК1 увидеть расшаренную папку на ПК3
ПК2 видит, что понятно.
Подскажите как правильно прописать маршрут, а то сам никак((

Comment: посмотрите здесь : https://techarks.ru/general/osobennosti/kak-sozdat-setevoj-most-v-windows-10-8-7/

Comment: ПК 1 имеет доступ в Инет. В этом случае ПК3 получит доступ в Инет? Сейчас не имеет. Если таки получит - не подходит((